# Start a container from another one in a pod in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have a container that performs some actions over some data. This container is heavy in memory and CPU resources, and I want it to start only an on-demand basis.

As an example, with docker-compose, out of Kubernetes, I use it this way:

```
docker-compose run heavycontainer perform.sh some-action
```

The container performs the action and ends.

In Kubernetes I want this container to perform the actions it provides, but in response to some messages (AMQP messages, created by other containers). I have a container that listens for messages. My first thought was a pod with two containers: listener and performer. But I don't know whether is possible or not start a container from another.

Init or sidecar containers doesn't seem a solution. And I prefer to avoid creating a custom image to inject the listener into the performer.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

<strike>I hope it help you.</strike>

- The pod need to `run regularly`, [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job)
- The pod need to `run on demand`, [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/)

Firstly, I apologize you about my wrong answer.

I understand what you want now, and I think it can be available to run multiple containers in same pod. [Patterns for Application Augmentation on OpenShift](https://blog.openshift.com/patterns-application-augmentation-openshift/) is helpful for you.

PS. OpenShift is Enterprise Kubernetes, so you can think OpenShift is same with Kubernetes.

Comment: Interesting reading, thanks. But those are the three cases I tried or want to avoid: init and sidecar containers has no control over other containers in pod, and the third case is about building a custom image.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Horizontal Pod Autoscaling (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) for orchestrating your heavycontainer, based on number of relevant messages in the queue.

Comment: The link provided does not mention horizontal scaling based "messages in a queue". Can you please provide more details? Unless you mean beta api only CPU based is supported.

Comment: @ucipass, I mean HPA based on custom metrics, see for instance https://towardsdatascience.com/kubernetes-hpa-with-custom-metrics-from-prometheus-9ffc201991e :
"The K8s Horizontal Pod Autoscaler:
is implemented as a control loop that periodically queries the Resource Metrics API for core metrics, through metrics.k8s.io API, like CPU/memory and the Custom Metrics API for application-specific metrics (external.metrics.k8s.io or custom.metrics.k8s.io API."